# crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: google-fabric

about week ago we has been successfully integrate crashlytics in our cocos2d-x c++ project (ndk 14b). Everything looks fine, but about few days ago task crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease starts throw this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':woh:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease'.
> GC overhead limit exceeded
```

javaMaxHeapSize "4g", javaMaxHeapSize "16g", org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m, and so on doesn't help us. But crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug is working fine:

```
:woh:assembleX86Debug
:woh:compileDebugSources
:woh:assembleDebug
:woh:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug
:woh:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug
:woh:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5 mins 15.064 secs
```

What we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have just released Fabric Gradle Plugin 1.24.3, which is still in beta and causes this issue. Reverting to 1.24.2 solves it.

Check your build.gradle file and force the previous version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.2'
}
```

Source: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

Comment: I received confirmation from their support that this was a mistake on their end.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. Yep, we fixed the bug. Use version 1.24.4 to get the fix.