# crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease - StackOverflowError

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

A few weeks ago we had a problem - plugin crashlytics used in our build was crashed with message:

```
:packageRelease
:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease
:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease
:lintVitalRelease
:assembleRelease
:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

We have no problem when builduing project in Debug mode, only when trying Release mode.

On this issue found similar by the link ([crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease - GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792489/crashlyticsgeneratesymbolsrelease-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)), but it did not help.

---

Versions of plugins we use:

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.4@aar')
```

Log from gradle with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.padLong(NamedRangeIndex.java:542)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.referenceBytesAsLong(NamedRangeIndex.java:525)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.attributeValue(NamedRangeIndex.java:475)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:419)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:400)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:390)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:400)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:390)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:400)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:390)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:400)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntryAndAttribute(NamedRangeIndex.java:422)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.utils.elf.index.NamedRangeIndex.symbolNameFromEntrySequence(NamedRangeIndex.java:390)
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you add your app's build.gradle?

Comment: We have 2 files: for app and for engine. 

App - https://gist.github.com/DrSterling/455698a4faed0adb633e7ea782c03180

Engine - https://gist.github.com/DrSterling/926c8ddb028d5fd33e0878d8d97ff6e0

Comment: Hmnm, all that looks fine. Any conditional logic around initializing Fabric?

Comment: In addition, I sent an e-mail via the contact form at https://support.crashlytics.com/ with attached minimal project which emulate crash. E-mail was sent on August 07, 2018 at 6:52 AM
Maybe this will be helpfull

Comment: Thanks, will follow up over email.

Comment: We still have a question. Did you manage to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hey @DrSterling. Did you find a solution? I'm hitting the same issue.